# moviepy write_videofile giving error on remote host

Tags: python, ffmpeg, watermark, moviepy, oserror

I'm trying to put a logo on a video using the moviepy module
This module works properly on my PC(windows) but gives an error when I run the following code on the remote host I bought(linux).

code :

```
import random
import moviepy.editor as mp
import requests


def video_watermark(url):
    corners = [("right", "top"), ("left", "top"), ("right", "bottom"), ("left", "bottom")]
    response = requests.get(url)
    with open("media/videos/raw_video.mp4", "wb") as file:
        file.write(response.content)

    video = mp.VideoFileClip("./media/videos/raw_video.mp4")

    logo = (mp.ImageClip("./media/bold_logo.png")
            .set_duration(video.duration)
            .resize(height=50)  # if you need to resize...
            .margin(right=8, top=8, opacity=0)  # (optional) logo-border padding
            .set_pos(random.choice(corners)))

    final = mp.CompositeVideoClip([video, logo])
    final.write_videofile("./media/videos/ready_video.mp4")

video_watermark("url")
```

error :

```
OSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
 
MoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the following error while writing
file ./media/videos/ready_video.mp4:
 
b'Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder
for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate,
rate, width or height\n'
```

please help me to fix this problem

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first you should check if server get correct file `raw_video.mp4`. Some servers blocks access to external servers to stop spamers/bots/scrapers/hackers. You could download it and test on local server. And you could open it in text editor to see if you don't get HTML with some message.

Comment: maybe it has `FFMPEG` which can read `mp4` but it can't save `mp4`. It may need to install it from source code and add all needed codecs. What Linux do you have on server? Ubuntu, Debian, other? What version? You could also check if you can in console run `ffmpeg -i raw_video.mp4 ready_video.mp4`. Maybe it will show more information.